# How does Calm Heart work?

Tags: world-of-darkness, werewolf-20th-anniversary

I'm looking at merits for an Ahroun in a city, and Calm Heart is confusing me a little.

> Calm Heart (3 pt. Merit)
>
> You remain calm and collected even in the most
>   trying of circumstances. You receive two extra dice when
>   attempting to resist frenzy

I can't figure out when and how this would apply.
- You enter frenzy when you make a rage check and have 4 or more successes.
- You exit a rage with a willpower check.
The only reference I can find in the book to resisting frenzy is that granted by rank, which increases the difficulty of frenzy checks.

Comment: I have a feeling it might be an error, left over from V20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed sounds like an error reprinted from V20 series. Since there is no official errata that I know about, I've found the same merit in [Werewolf Player guide](https://www.scribd.com/document/24496858/Mental-Merits-and-Flaws) (this is also how it is described in [Dark Force Mush Wiki](http://darkforcesmush.wikia.com/wiki/Merit:_Calm_Heart) )

> Calm Heart
>   : (3 pt Merit) You are naturally calm and well composed, in the most trying of circumstances, andyou rarely fly off the handle. Raise the difficulty on all your frenzy rolls by 2, no matter how any incident is provoked

If you don't want to go with the above, there is MET version

> Calm Heart (3 Trait Merit) -- Restricted. You have a relatively even-keeled temperament, for a werewolf. You are one Trait up on tests to resist Frenzy. ([tcgarou](http://tcgarou.pbworks.com/w/page/24414580/Merits))

Comment: That second one is a [tag:minds-eye-theatre] one—you can tell from the use of the word "trait," which is not applicable for tabletop.